# How to import csv's with "occasional" quotes (R and / or Pandas)?

Tags: python, r, excel, csv, pandas

I ran across a new problem today.  I discovered some data that I'm working with, that looks like this (in a `csv` file):

```
Male,White,All Combined,1989,30-31,31,"59,546","18,141","328,235"
Male,White,Felony - Drug,1989,30-31,31,"3,861","1,176","328,235"
Male,White,Felony - Other,1989,30-31,31,"2,626",800,"328,235"
Male,White,Felony - Property,1989,30-31,31,"3,468","1,057","328,235"
Male,White,Felony - Violent/Sex,1989,30-31,31,"3,150",960,"328,235"
Male,White,Misdemeanor,1989,30-31,31,"46,441","14,149","328,235"
Male,White,Status,1989,30-31,31,0,0,"328,235"
```

It's hard to see the problem, so let me highlight the ***second to last column***:

```
"18,141"
"1,176"
800
"1,057"
960
"14,149"
0
```

The problem is **values with commas are being exported as strings, while values without commas are exported as numbers**.  To be clear, the data ***should*** be interpreted as:

```
18141
1176
800
1057
960
14149
0
```

That is, it should all be interpreted as numeric values.

However, it makes me think that ***some*** "standard" application is exporting data like this.  For the moment, let's say that it is Excel.

Is there any effective way to try to import flat files with this ***varying*** data type within the same column?  Both R (`read_csv` from `readr` library) and Python's Pandas (`read_csv`), using their standard flags, interpreted this data by doing the following:

- Presuming they should ***all*** be numbers (regardless of whether or not quotes are present in all "cells").
- Presuming that the commas, therefore, must be the European-style of using a comma for a decimal place (instead of the US period).
- So, both packages interpreted that column as follows:

  ```
  18.141
  1.176
  800
  1.057
  960
  14.149
  0
  ```

In a way, it's impressive that both R (`read_csv` from `readr` library) and Pandas (`read_csv`) could both handle this incongruity and get the guesses **almost** right.

However, is there a flag that I can set or a package out there which can handle this sort of thing?  For instance, a flag to say "remove quoted commas, they are most certainly **not** European for our US decimal place.

If not, is there enough of a need to contribute to this via forking either of their GitHub repos?

Comment: If you inconsistent formatting within the same column then you need to perform some pre/post-processing

Comment: @Prune I edited the question, so that it is hopefully clearer.  In short, I do need what you wrote.

Comment: @EdChum Yes, you're absolutely right that some pre-processing is needed.  I took care of it.  However, this appears to be a common means of exporting by some apps.  In fact, I just tested this on Excel, and if I place the comma, it will export as shown here (different format based upon whether row has a comma).  My goal, here, is to be able to properly interpret this column without a problem.  It is "easy" if, for instance, a flag is added where I can say "not European", therefore, any number can be scrubbed for commas, instead of interpreting as a decimal.

Comment: What OS are you on?  We can probably do this quickly at the command line

Comment: @RichardScriven Yes, command line pre-processing can handle it, and I know how to do that.  I'm instead looking to more effectively use the tools themselves (R or Pandas).  This will allow for a more generalized solution across a wider range of data munging problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.read_csv` has `thousands=','` parameter which you can set to a comma so pandas will read your column as

```
0    18141
1     1176
2      800
3     1057
4      960
5    14149
6        0
```

Also there is a `converters` parameter that takes a dictionary of columns and corresponding functions for applying to each column. You can use it for more complex preprocessing, something like this (does the same thing):

`pd.read_csv('data.csv', converters={'column_name': lambda x: int(x.replace(',',''))})`

Comment: While "thousands" does solve the problem, I was looking more generically for a way to say that the quote and/or escape characters may vary WITHIN the column.  Your converters parameter will do exactly that, in a more generic fashion!  Thanks!